# Custom fields with value not pushing with wp_remote_post to wp site

Tags: post-meta, rest-api, json, remote

I want to share current post to another WP site with wp_remote_post function, so i created a post template and then select that to remote site with submit button. I have created code it's working fine for title, body, category, tags, featured image, template but custom fields not inserting on remote site. Same code is working on third website but not on second site, after execution Post Created Successfully is showing but don't know where is actual issue. -

```
$login = 'username'; // Author role
$password = 'xxx xxxx xxxx';
     
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $post_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_title']);
    $content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_content']);
  
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    // Get the selected template
    $template_post = sanitize_text_field($_POST['template_post']);
    $categories = isset($_POST['post_categories']) ? array_map('intval', $_POST['post_categories']) : array();
    $tags = isset($_POST['post_tags']) ? array_map('intval', $_POST['post_tags']) : array();

    // Define an array of custom field names
    $custom_fields = array(
        'Meta1', 'Meta2'
    );

  $custom_fields_data = array();

    // Define the original and replacement domain
    $original_domain = 'one.com';
    $new_domain = 'two.com';

    foreach ($custom_fields as $field) {
        $field_value = get_post_meta($post_id, $field, true);
        if (!empty($field_value)) {
            // Check if the field is 'Meta1' and contains the original domain
            if ($field === 'Meta1' && strpos($field_value, $original_domain) !== false) {
                $field_value = str_replace($original_domain, $new_domain, $field_value);
            }

            $custom_fields_data[$field] = $field_value;
        }
    }

    $slug = basename(get_permalink());

    $post_data = array(
        'title' => $post_title,
        'status' => 'draft',
        'content' => $content,
        'meta' => $custom_fields_data,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'tags' => $tags,
        'template' => $template_post,
        'slug' => $slug
    );

    // Encode the data as JSON
    $post_data = json_encode($post_data);

    // Send the post data to the remote website
    $response = wp_remote_post('https://www.two.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
 
 array(
            'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$login:$password"),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ),
            'body' => $post_data,
        )
    );

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        echo "Error: " . $response->get_error_message();
    } else {
        $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
        if ($response_code === 201) {
            $post_id = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response))->id;
            echo '<p>Post Created Successfully.</p>';
        } else {
            echo "Failed to create the post. Response code: " . $response_code;
        }
    }
}

?>
```